# Syntax error code worked earlier but now it doesnt

Tags: python, syntax

I'm having an error and it worked earlier but it now just doesn't, any tips?

SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call this is the error and I know where it is located, I really no longer have any idea why its like.from io import open_code
import time

```
    

def count1():
    for xa in range(1,900000000000000000000000000000000000000000): # loop

        time.sleep(1) 

        with open('door4.txt','w') as f1: # file (think of it as number 1)

            f1.write(str(xa)) # writes the number into the file door 4

            with open('door5.txt','r') as f2: # another file, 
#this one gets saved to the file, the other part (above)is only there for throughout the session
                cant = f2.read() # becomes the saved string value '1'

                varpir = int(cant) = int(cant) + 1 #here is the issue it says the error
#if you delete a few lines then it works but not how I want it to work





                with open('door5.txt', "w") as f3: #same file above but with write priveleges
                    f3.write(str(varpir)) # writes the code
                    print(xa) # prints the code of door4
                    print(varpir) # prints the code of door5
        






def all():
    count1() 



all() # the line that runs it all
```

Comment: the error is at the variable called varpir, varpir is a variable of a variable, might that be the issue?

Comment: varpir is supposed to 'calculate' and transfer them into an int value

Comment: the error line: SyntaxError: "can't assign to function call"
code works perfectly fine without the varpir line and some other lines removed, so the issue is at the varpir line

Comment: I think you want `varpir = cant = int(cant) + 1`

Comment: You can't have `int(cant)` on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: `varpir = int(cant) = int(cant)` was never valid Python syntax. It isn't clear what you mean... perhaps just `varpir  = int(cant)`

Comment: @Oabbd That means that your value from `cant` can't be converted to an integer

Comment: @Marcel no, that isn't what it means, that wouldn't raise a SyntaxError, but a ValueError

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it gets a value error because there's nothing inside the door5.txt, if there is a text value then it will basically work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @Oabbd changed the comment from saying `ValueError`  to `SyntaxError`...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for not making it clear what I want! What I want is that the code works without any errors, the current error is at the varpir variable line, I tried doing this but this just gives another error, the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

edit: the file data got flushed so it was empty causing it to crash, this is actually the solution, thanks though

````
                varpir  = int(cant)
                varpir = varpir + int(1)```   ''
````

Comment: If your problem is solved you can close the issue.